# The usage of “If I was going to eat” and “If I am going to eat”

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

The meaning of “if I will go” is very clearly explained by [John Lawler here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61299/if-i-go-vs-if-i-will-go-referring-to-the-future), better than I could ever find in any grammar book.

Both deontic and epistemic sense leave no doubt about their meaning.

Clearly, a future tense construction made with modal verb “will” cannot be used in English following if, for if it used would mean anything else, except future.

I wonder what would be the meaning of another variant to construct the future tense (e.g.) “going to” if it follows “if”:
[If I'm gonna eat somebody It might as well be you !](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-are-the-lyrics-to-if-im-gonna-eat-somebody-from-the-movie-ferngully)

What would be the diffrence betwen : "If I was going to eat” and "If I am going to eat”?

Comment: I think the hypothetical sentence you said should be written as the subjunctive mood. Said that, shouldn't it read *If I **were** going to eat..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I am going to eat somebody, it might as well be you.

This is acceptable. The prohibition against futurive *will* is a prohibition against that word in that sense, not the future reference. In any case, *be going to* in this context is present-focused: it expresses present intention or expectation of a future event.

*It might as well be you* literally means “You would serve as well as (or better than) another as object of my eating.” In actual use, however, there is no modality or tentativeness here. *Might as well* in this context announces a *decision* to accept an invitation or opportunity:

> **A:** Wanna go grab a beer?
>   **B:** Might as well.
>   (Actually, in my dialect it would be “Mought's well. Can’t dance, and it’s too wet to plow.”)

The sentence may be paraphrased “Given my intention of eating somebody,  I have decided to eat you.”

---

> If I was going to eat somebody, it ... ?

This is trickier. *Was* here is acceptable colloquially as a variant of formal *were*. In some contexts it might express uncertainty or hypotheticality, but in the context of my intention it almost has to express counterfactuality: “I do not at present intend to eat somebody, but if I *did* ... ”

Consequently, *it might as well be you* cannot follow this. Grammatically it would be acceptable, but semantically the firm intention it expresses does not suit a counterfactual situation. And since its past-irrealis form (*might*) is already completely ‘modalized’, it cannot be modalized any further. To the best of my knowledge, even dialects which accept modal stacking will not permit this:

> <sup>∗</sup> ... it would might as well be you.

So you have to find an alternative expression. The closest I can get to a counterfactual version of the original is something like this:

> If I was gonna eat somebody it’d definitely be you.

Comment: I think the hypothetical sentence OP said should be written as the subjunctive mood. Said that, shouldn't it read *If I **were** going to eat..."

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you for your piece of English at its very best!

Comment: @MaulikV As I said, conversational English increasingly employs the ordinary past form as an irrealis. I expect what traditional grammar calls the 'subjunctive' (it's not a subjunctive, but that's another question!) to be fully dodo-ized in two or three generations.